# Problem reading a double from file with 1 decimal place (C)

Tags: c

For some reason when I try to read in a double and print it out with this code, it prints out:
"865955189279958860000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000"

```
    fscanf(inFile, "%.1lf", &value);
    printf("%.lf\n", value);
```

When I change the code to this:

```
    fscanf(inFile, "%lf", &value);
    printf("%.1lf\n", value);
```

I get the output I want. But obviously I want the double to be stored as 8.1 (for instance), rather than having to format when I print it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's in the file??

Comment: `I want the double to be stored as "8.1" (for instance), rather than having to format when I print it.` - what? What do you mean by "double stored as 8.1"?

Comment: Using `"%.1lf"` is valid for `printf()` but not `fscanf()`.  Drop the dot `.`.  And check the return value from `fscanf()` — it would probably tell you that there were problems.

Comment: Yep meant 8.1 not "8.1", good catch haha

Comment: @nicomp 
2 3 6.0 would be a single line in the file. only having issue reading in 6.0 as is. it stores 6.0 as 6.0000 ( or something)

Comment: Actually, using `%1lf` would read a single digit — it probably isn't what you want — but the dot is definitely not right.  You don't show the actual input.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler removing the dot definitely helped as it no longer prints out 86595518927995886etc, but it still stores the double with 6 decimal spaces

Comment: Note that printing with `%.1lf` would print just one decimal place.  However, you need to decide whether to specify a width during input, and what is stored will depend on the width (if any) and the value specified.  For example, if you type 987.321 as the input, and use just `%lf`, then the value stored would be `987.321`, but if you display it with `%.1lf`, then you'd see `987.3`.  Etc.

Comment: "but it still stores the double with 6 decimal spaces" --> No. that is an incorrect conclusion about what is stored.

Answer (score 2):

A [`double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) has always a certain number of significant decimal digits, for example IEEE 754 gives 15 to 17. So you can't limit stored values to an arbitrary number of decimal places, let alone the problem of **decimal** fractions represented by **binary** numbers. For example, there is no way to **exactly** store 6.1 in an IEEE-754-`double`.

Anyway, you might like to round the value. But again, be aware of the problem mentioned above.

If you like to have an output with a limited number of decimal places, just use the corresponding format string, for example `"%.1lf"`. The default number is 6 that's why you think it's stored like this.

But the best solution for you might be to use `"%g"`. *Note: It's always a good idea to read documentation, in this case for `printf()`.*